# How can I use $.ajax to POST accented characters (eg. > ASCII 127)?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Suppose I type an accented character, such as ASCII 233, into a form like this:

[image]

Then I use this code to post. Key point, as I understand it: URL encoding is not viable with ASCII > 127, so you have to induce a different content type.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/third_party/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#but').click(function(){
                    var fd = new FormData();    
                    fd.append( 'params', $('#inp').val());
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://my-server-address-here',
                        data: fd,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <input id="inp"></input>
    <button id="but">Submit</button>
</html>
```

The problem is, Chrome still seems to mangle the character, as shown here. This is before it even gets to the server-side script, however, outputting it from there shows the same problem.

[image]

We **output** data (eg server to browser) of this type all the time with no issues or special logic, so, I think it must be possible to make my 'French e' show up server-side without any special translation or conversion, other than configuring the browser and request properly, which I assume I am failing to do. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Why are there two `contentType` keys?

Comment: Try `fd.append( 'params', encodeURIComponent($('#inp').val()))`

Comment: @BradM, my mistake, but it doesn't affect the outcome either way. Edited to only show the second / false value.

Comment: @mplungjan that does the same thing that using x-www-form-urlencoded would do, which results in the wrong value server-side because URL encoding is (as I understand it) not intended for ASCII values > 127.

Comment: URL encoding turns a single accented 'e' into two bytes, %C3%A9. Decoding those back returns two separate characters that bear no relation to the original input. Again, I think this is because URL encoding isn't intended for these types of characters, but I'm hoping someone can explain otherwise.

Comment: Should work: Encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters). The "FormData should already have handled that: It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data". Perhaps dont use formdata and jQuery at the same time

Comment: What server are you using to read this form data?  Somehow you need to tell it to expect UTF-8.

Comment: As an aside, %C3%A9 is the correct encoding for the two-byte UTF-8 character "é".  Percent-encoding can handle all unicode characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your example works fine.  You've already told the browser to treat this page as UTF-8 in the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` tag, meaning it will submit the form data as UTF-8.  Percent-encoding is irrelevant here as you're sending the character as part of the http body (as multipart/form-data).

The characters you see in Chrome's developer tools are a result of the dev tools treating your single-character é as two single-byte characters, rather than as a two-byte UTF-8 character.  Your server should properly read the two bytes as a single character, not as two characters like chrome dev tools does.

(I just tested your example using a Node.js server, and the server properly interpreted the form body as UTF-8, returning "é", as input.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Developer Tools displays the 'e' correctly when you use the urlencoded form, but, that may not be relevant. I will do more rooting around server-side. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine and is somewhat simpler than your code

[<kbd>**live demo**</kbd>](http://plungjan.name/SO/utftest.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#but").click(function(){
                    var $data = { "params":$("#inp").val()};
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "dump.php",
                        data: $data,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#result").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <input id="inp" value="Français - Wikipédia"></input>
    <button id="but">Submit</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: So it seems like multipart/form-data thing is not true ... all that does is causes GC to screw up the display in the debugger but under the covers its OK either way. Thanks a lot, cheers.

Comment: @GregT if it is appreciated and Johann's answer is too, please click the ^ above the vote number